# Need to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss UTC to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format

Tags: r

How can I convert :

```
2019-01-22 18:30:33 UTC
```

to

```
2019-01-22 18:30
```

with delating ss and UTC word.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R:

Assuming your date is a string. Make it a POSIX object and format whichever way you want it.

```
date_as_posix <- strptime("2019-01-22 18:30:33 UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
strftime(date_as_posix, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")
[1] "2019-01-22 18:30"
```

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

An option is `floor_date` assuming that the OP still want a Datetime object

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(ymd_hms(str1), 'minute')
#[1] "2019-01-22 18:30:00 UTC"
```

If the intention is to get a string, then use `format`

```
format(ymd_hms(str1), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2019-01-22 18:30"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '2019-01-22 18:30:33 UTC'
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work and str1 should be `2019-01-22 18:30:00 UTC` and not `2019-01-22 18:30:33`

Comment: @SA2018 When you do the `ymd_hms`, it converts it to DateTime object.  I changed it to your exact  string and is working fine for me

Comment: @SA2018 It is a bit strange that the solution is not working for you.  May be please check the package version of lubridate